# Increase HTTP Request Rate To Third Party API

Tags: node.js, http-request

I'm writing an application that relies on a third party API for data. I'm trying to see how many requests can be completed in a certain time period and what I can do to increase the amount.

For testing, I'm using the following node script:

```
var requrest = require('request');
var async = require('async'
var url = 'api-end-point.com/api';
var count = 500;
var token = 'api-token';

var start = Date.now();
async.times(count, function(n, next) {
    req = request({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            authorization: token
        }
    }, function(err, res, body) {
        console.log('Completed request #' + n + '...Data = ', body);
        next();
    });
}, function(err, results) {
    var stop = Date.now();
    var diff = stop - start;
    var timeInSeconds = diff / 1000;
    var avgRequestTime = timeInSeconds / count;

    console.log('Total Request Count = ', count);
    console.log('Total Time = ', timeInSeconds, ' seconds');
    console.log('Average request time = ', avgRequestTime, ' seconds');
});
```

On my server I've been able to process 500 requests at around 30 - 35 seconds, at an average request rate of around 65ms per completed request. I've also tried running this on different sized servers but that didn't seem to have much effect. Is there anything that I can do to increase the amount of requests that are complete with a single machine, or is this controlled by the API server that I'm contacting? Is there a way to scale my system other than by adding on more servers on my end to query the API?

Comment: `async.times()` will run the requests in parallel (500 at once), which may cause congestion on the machine you're running the test script on. Try using [`async.timesLimit()`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.timesLimit) to limit the amount of concurrent requests to, say, 50, to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I tried doing this but it didn't have much of an effect. Average time per  request remained the same.